MIC5014BN output looks like a staircase instead of a nice square Wave
The input of the MIC5014 is an output pin of an arduino nano that output a square wave at 60 khz and 75% duty cycle. Pin 3 and 4 are shorted to ground as i wish to drive a mosfet in a low side configuration.
This is pretty much the example schematic in the datasheet but with no load or MOSFET (the output pin is floating) :

I'm using a 12v battery as a supply, when i probe the output pin of the MIC5014 the output looks like this : 
I was expecting something more like a square wave, i'm afraid that the mosfet will not be fully on for the first μs and thus heat up.

Please show schematic and component types/values.

I have edited the post to add a schematic. Regarding the components there is just the mic5014, a regular Arduino Nano and a 12v bike battery

The data sheet has several relevant statements:
Chapter "Functional Description" (emphasized by me):

When the input is driven to the “ON” state, the N-channel switches are turned off, the charge pump is turned on, and the P-channel switch between the charge pump and the gate turns on, allowing the gate of the power FET to be charged.


The charge pump incorporates a 100kHz oscillator and on-chip pump capacitors capable of charging a 1,000pF load in 90μs typical.

Chapter "Typical Characteristics":

So you see the starting of the internal charge pump, with its oscillator's frequency not much higher than your PWM frequency.
This device is apparently not meant for such usage.

The datasheet also indicates there is a 15 V zener which which limits the output of the charge pump. I think that explains why the scope picture in the question shows the Gate voltage is nominally 15 V with some apparent spikes up to 20 V.

Thank you, i overlooked that part of the datasheet
